# Altium bug: White trace outlines on layer wont go away

Tags: altium

My PCB in altium is presenting with a "ghost" of previous traces. They occur only on the one layer. Deleting the surrounding traces does not remove them - moving the components does not move or remove them.

How can i get rid of these glitches? Also where did they come from??

Last thing i need is these ghost traces impacting exported gerbers!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried exporting the GERBER and viewing it in softwares like eg. Viewplot

Comment: The gerbers are not affected, but still not cool having some strange artifact on the design :(

Comment: Reopen .pcbdoc, it might help.

Comment: What happens if you hit "Clear" in the bottom right-hand corner of the PCB editor screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reckon it's an error mark. Try T-M enter to Reset Error Markers